# Unable to boot Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS after installation

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, grub-efi, initramfs

I have downloaded Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.1 LTS and created a bootable USB (16GB) drive using Rufus in order to install Ubuntu onto my computer alongside Windows. I have a more than sufficient sized partition for ubuntu ready to use.

I have installed and reinstalled Ubuntu many times now and still can't get it to boot. Prior to installation I get the following text flash at the top off the screen.

```
[   0.375821] Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed

[   0.554209] integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -22
```

It then proceeds to the installation prompts and it appears to install without any  other issues however it won't actually boot Ubuntu.

I make sure when I'm installing to connect to the internet and allow all updates and third party applications in hopes this will download a fix but it doesn't appear to do so.

I even tried to install an earlier Ubuntu LTS (18.04.5) however I ran into the same problem except the only error was:

```
[   0.554209] integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -22
```

Can anyone help me with this?
I have conducted verification checks and disk integrity checks each stating that there is nothing wrong with iso and nothing wrong with the boot disk.

P.S. I followed every instruction in the ubuntu desktop tutorial exactly and the same with the create bootable USB tutorial and Rufus tutorial/guide.

Comment: Please be specific on release, as many users of the site mean different things with regards the *latest*  (Ubuntu 20.04.1 was not the latest release, the last was 16.04.7 or a new ISO for an older release). The message "*Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed*" makes me think of *squashfs* errors on boot, did validation of the media complete successfully?

Comment: Do you have UEFI Secure Boot on? "Problem loading X.509 certificate -22" often is related to that. May be called "Windows" or "Other" in UEFI settings.

Comment: @guiverc , my apologies on the version error. I’m new to this and thought it was the latest because it is what defaulted on the website :). What do you mean by validation of the media?

Comment: @oldfred , I have tried with both, UEFI secure boot ON and OFF thus far it doesn’t seem to have made a difference.

Comment: I mean verify the ISO https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 and more importantly in my experience verify the write to media (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck) which was a separate *optional* step before 20.04; on your boot you'll see it perform and it gives you an option to skip (don't skip) and reports it's complete (it doesn't wait long) then boots to the *live* desktop. On VMs with too limited RAM check can pass but it experiences *squashfs* errors anyway. If you can't confirm media on that box, use another box to verify media

Comment: I'm still not sure what release you're talking about. Ubuntu with two digit (*yy*) releases are different products to the 2digit.2digit *yy.mm* release so please be precise. Desktop & server releases are *yy.mm* in format (ie. *year.month* of release), there are no desktop releases using *yy* format; *yy* are special purpose releases for appliances, devices & not standard computers.

Comment: @guiverc - sorry the release I’m trying to use is 20.04 LTS. Hopefully those tutorials help. I’ll see about trying get them sorted today and I’ll post an update when it’s done. 
Cheers for your help bud. At the moment this stuff goes over my head. Some things I understand and others leave me feeling blank.

Comment: @guiverc - I am trying to install 20.04.1 LTS. I attempted to verify the ISO utilising the Ubuntu app and PowerShell however neither are working as the tutorial suggest. I have followed every step as it has asked and yet it is not working.

Comment: I have managed to conduct and verification of the ISO with success and I have managed to verify the write to media. Still returning the same errors as above.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me after hours of trying other numerous other fixes such as various ways of verifying media, verifying ISO, disabling secure boot and various setting changes when creating bootable media.

- Change boot settings from UEFI to CSM.
- Install Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.
- Connect to internet and update Ubuntu to 20.04.1 LTS.